# How do you return a value from a MessagingCenter call?

Tags: xamarin.forms

We are using Xamarin.Forms for our project and subscribed a MessagingCenter call onto the `DisplayAlert` and `DisplayActionSheet` native functions.

Here's how we subscribed it in our view:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ViewModelBase, List<string>> (this, "DisplayActionSheet", (sender, values) => {
    string title = values[0];
    values.RemoveAt(0);
    DisplayActionSheet (title, "Annuler", null, values.ToArray());
});
```

Here's how we implemented it in our `ViewModel`:

```
public async void DisplayActionSheet(string title, string[] actions){
    List<string> values = new List<string>(actions);
    values.Insert (0, title);
    MessagingCenter.Send<ViewModelBase, List<string>> (this, "DisplayActionSheet", values);
}
```

So we can call it this way:

```
string[] actions = {"Charmander", "Pikachu", "Squirtle"};
DisplayActionSheet("Choose your pokemon", actions);
```

How can we return a value to the message sender?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem myself; would you mind sharing the solution you chose, if any?

Answer (score 1):

You could send back the result of the DisplayActionSheet via the MessagingCenter.

For example

```
await result = DisplayActionSheet(....);
MessagingCenter.Send<MyPage, string> (this, "DisplayResult", result);
// Then where you need it
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPage, string> (this, "DisplayResult", (sender, displayResultString) => {
    // do something with displayResultString
});
```